# Angular 2 http catch observable issue

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular2-http

I have a custom http service which overrides default angular 2 http service. This service sets custom default options and set loader on request start and hides loader on request completion.

I also want to add, the functionality to redirect user to the login page in case if Unauthorized error (401, 403) is received from server. For example below is my http method

```
get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<any> {
        this.setLoadingStatus();
        options = this.prepareOptions(options);
        let that = this;
        return super.get(url, options)
            .map(res => {
                this.clearLoadingStatus();
                return res.json();
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                //redirects user to login and display alert
                that._gs.alertUnauthorized();
                return Observable.empty();
            });
    }
```

But when test it in browser i.e. make a request for protected page that returns 401 in case of unauthorized request, it doest redirect to the login page but console displays below error:

```
GET http://localhost:49547/api/protected/ 401 (Unauthorized)
EXCEPTION: Observable_1.Observable.empty is not a function
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE:
TypeError: Observable_1.Observable.empty is not a function
```

Can anyone please guide?

Comment: Try `super.get().map((res) => {}, (err) => {});` syntax?

Answer (score 2):

You need to import the `empty` function:

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/empty'
```

Comment: Thank you, this was helpful. Please also guide that if using Observable.empty() in this case is appropriate, or is there any other better option?

Comment: I still see the below error line printed in console "zone.js:1274 GET http://localhost:49547/proteccted/ 401 (Unauthorized)", is it okay? or is it an exception that needs to be handled?

Comment: I think it's just a debugging thing. Returning Observable.empty() supresses the error, so if that's what you want, you're golden.

Comment: When server returns 401 unauthorized, I want to redirect to Login page.